# Why is there Apple copyright on lpadmin, lpq and lpstat pages?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apple

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Why do lpadmin,lpq, lpstat man pages have Apple copyright on them?

Answer (score 4):

That is because those programs are part of [cups](https://www.cups.org/), developed by Apple.

That a program (suite) is open source doesn't mean that the developer, or the company (partly) paying for development cannot claim copyright on their effort.

Answer (score 2):

CUPs was once an independent project, but was [purchased by Apple](https://www.cups.org/blog.php?L475) in 2007 from the CUPs creator, Michael Sweet, as mentioned in the [CUPS Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS).

Answer (score 1):

GNU/Linux is written by many many people. Not just by Ubuntu. Ubuntu took a distribution (like a compilation album, do you remember them?) from Debian, and “improved it”.

This compilation/distribution from Debian is a collection of software from many sources including:

- The GNU project for the compiler, some libraries, and a lot of userland tools.
- X11 from Xorg, originally from MIT.
- Gnome, KDE or another windowing manager / session manager.
- Applications such as Firefox, LibreOffice, VLC, …
- Linux (the kernel),
- and 7 DVDs more of other programs.

This could not be written by one company. (Note when you get your DVDs from Microsoft they are not full and contain a **LOT** of duplication.)

Most contributors copy-write there work, this is how GPL and most other Free-Software licences work. The only exception may be to assign to the public domain (this is a non-copywrite Free licence).